# Use of undeclared type "tagCell" Error. Creating UICollectionViewCell that kind of xib

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to build tag flow layout and I was following this topic;

http://codentrick.com/create-a-tag-flow-layout-with-uicollectionview/

Then this code threw this error : `Use of undeclared type 'tagCell'`.

```
var tagCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("tagCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tagCell
```

I created these files; a xib called `tagCell.xib`, a file called `tagCell.swift`. And I connected these files under xib's custom class. I don't know what is the problem and I followed the topic without missing. Maybe there was some changes about it in swift 2.

I need help. I looked for ready to use libraries written via swift but I didn't find. I have to code it myself for now.

There are the classes.

```
//
//  tagCell.swift
//  matchMyTag
//
//  Created by Faruk Turgut on 05/12/15.
//

import UIKit

class tagCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tagTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)
        self.tagTitle.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1)
        self.plusLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4

    }

}
```

---

```
//
//  skillsNeedsViewController.swift
//  matchMyTag
//
//  Created by Faruk Turgut on 05/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Faruk Turgut. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class skillsNeedsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let TAGS = ["Tech", "Design", "Humor", "Travel", "Music", "Writing", "Social Media", "Life", "Education", "Edtech", "Education Reform", "Photography", "Startup", "Poetry", "Women In Tech", "Female Founders", "Business", "Fiction", "Love", "Food", "Sports"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "tagCell", bundle: nil)
        self.collectionView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "tagCell")
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return TAGS.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var tagCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("tagCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tagCell

        return tagCell
    }


}
```

Comment: just updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Reuse Identifier on your cell.

Just open your storyboard, select the cell from the collection view and set it like the following:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also, you must always name your classes using [CamelCase](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). **So change the class name, the .swift file name and wherever you wants to call the class call it TagCell**. The broken line should now look like this:

```
var tagCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("tagCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TagCell
```

Comment: it didn't work. there is something wrong still with `as! tagCell` part.

Answer (score 0):

for me it's working fine after quit Xcode and run again